# Mock issue with AngularJS and Jasmine

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

Tryin' to get started with testing in angularjs (based on [this](http://jsfiddle.net/brendanowen/5Afbm/1/)) but can't seem to get the mocks working correctly. Here's my jasmine file:

```
describe 'FlightsController', ->
  beforeEach module 'surf-air'

  beforeEach inject ($rootScope, $controller) ->
    scope = $rootScope.$new()
    FlightsController = $controller('FlightsController', {scope: scope})

  it 'should work', -> expect(true).toBe(true)
```

And here's what Testacular spits back:

```
Chrome 23.0 FlightsController should work FAILED
    Error: Unknown provider: $scopeProvider <- $scope
        at Error (<anonymous>)
        at /Users/chriskun/forge-workspace/surf-air-pilot-mobile/src/js/angular.min.js:28:395
        at Object.c [as get] (/Users/chriskun/forge-workspace/surf-air-pilot-mobile/src/js/angular.min.js:26:180)
        at /Users/chriskun/forge-workspace/surf-air-pilot-mobile/src/js/angular.min.js:28:476
        at c (/Users/chriskun/forge-workspace/surf-air-pilot-mobile/src/js/angular.min.js:26:180)
        at d (/Users/chriskun/forge-workspace/surf-air-pilot-mobile/src/js/angular.min.js:26:314)
        at Object.instantiate (/Users/chriskun/forge-workspace/surf-air-pilot-mobile/src/js/angular.min.js:27:455)
        at /Users/chriskun/forge-workspace/surf-air-pilot-mobile/src/js/angular.min.js:50:239
        at null.<anonymous> (/Users/chriskun/forge-workspace/surf-air-pilot-mobile/test/unit/controllers.js:9:34)
        at Object.d [as invoke] (/Users/chriskun/forge-workspace/surf-air-pilot-mobile/src/js/angular.min.js:27:325)
    Error: Declaration Location
        at window.jasmine.window.inject.angular.mock.inject (/Users/chriskun/forge-workspace/surf-air-pilot-mobile/test/lib/js/angular-mocks.js:1717:25)
        at null.<anonymous> (/Users/chriskun/forge-workspace/surf-air-pilot-mobile/test/unit/controllers.js:6:16)
        at /Users/chriskun/forge-workspace/surf-air-pilot-mobile/test/unit/controllers.js:4:3
        at /Users/chriskun/forge-workspace/surf-air-pilot-mobile/test/unit/controllers.js:18:4
Chrome 23.0: Executed 1 of 1 (1 FAILED) (0.221 secs / 0.04 secs)
```

which is caused by:

```
$controller('FlightsController', {scope: scope})
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change this line

```
FlightsController = $controller('FlightsController', {scope: scope})
```

to the following

```
FlightsController = $controller('FlightsController', {$scope: scope})
```

I have updated the example jsfiddle to CoffeeScript: http://jsfiddle.net/jaimem/5Afbm/2/

Comment: I've updated the OP with the separated beforeEach functions.. same error though.

Comment: pass a function call to module('surf-air') to `beforeEach`, not an anonymous function that calls `module`.

Comment: yeah tried that didn't change anything. updated the OP again.

Comment: apparently both ways work fine. The problem with your code seems to be that you are assigning the scope to the controller `scope` property, when it should be `$scope`

Comment: use strict';
(function() {
    describe('TabController: ', function () {
        var controller, scope;

        beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $rootScope) {
            debugger
            scope = $rootScope.$new();
            controller = $controller('itemListController', {scope: $scope});
        }));
rest of the code


Line 
controller = $controller('itemListController', {scope: $scope});

Gives error 
message
:
"Declaration Location"
stack
:
"Error: Declaration Location↵    at window.inject.angular.mock.inject
Where has the code gone wrong?